# Convert time format from chr to hours/minutes/seconds in R

Tags: r

See link attached. I want to change it form character to a time format so i can add a column with day/night.
Values are in this format:   00:30:00
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8znT6.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"hours/minutes/seconds"_, you may want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72322074/edit) your question and add an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be more successful in asking questions, it's better not to [post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're going for here, but...

The `as.ITime(...)` function in the `data.table` package does this:

```
as.ITime('00:30:00')
## [1] "00:30:00"
```

The result is stored internally as seconds:

```
as.integer(as.ITime('00:30:00'))
## [1] 1800
```

Comment: Hi jlhoward. Thanks for your comment. It says "no matches". I added a picture, does this make my question more clear?